# how do I shutdown my computer when multiple processes close?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, process, shutdown

I'm trying to make an auto shutdown application that will shutdown the computer when multiple processes close.

Example: The user has a checklistbox that lists all of the current running processes. The user check marks all desired processes that they wish to monitor.Once all of these processes close then the computer is supposed to shutdown. I am having trouble doing this, I don't know how to make the program check to see if the checked process items have closed. Here is some code that I have right now, I would appreciate all the help anyone can give me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;



namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int counter;



        Process[] p = Process.GetProcesses();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 100;




            foreach (Process plist in p)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(plist.ProcessName);
            }


        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            counter = 0;
            checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
            Process[] p = Process.GetProcesses();


            foreach (Process plist in p)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(plist.ProcessName);
                counter = counter + 1;

            }

                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("works");
                }

            }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }



    }
}
```

Thanks,

-Angel Mendez

Comment: The method I would use is to count all the running monitored processes in the timer. When that counter = 0, i would initiate the shutdown command.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, do you think you can show an example? thanks.

Comment: When your process finishes, just do a Process.Start("SHUTDOWN -s -t 01").  More info on the shutdown command here - http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace testprocessapp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] p = Process.GetProcesses();
            timer1.Interval = 10000;

            checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (Process plist in p)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(plist.ProcessName);
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int counter = 0;

            Process[] p = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in p)
            {
                foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.Items)
                {
                    if (item.ToString() == process.ProcessName)
                    {
                        counter = counter + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(counter == 0 ? "Your process has been terminated" : "Your process is still there");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

            foreach (var checkedItem in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                arrayList.Add(checkedItem);
            }

            checkedListBox1.DataSource = arrayList;

            //button1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Text = "Monitoring...";

            timer1.Start();


        }
    }
}
```

I have now created a replica of the application. This code works.

Comment: hi, I am using your method but I got an error for the "foreach(process pl in checklistbox1.checkeditems)" it is stating  "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Diagnostics.Process'." how can I fix this?

Comment: `foreach (var pl in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)`

Comment: I tried the code but it doesn't show me a messagebox showing that it worked, not sure what it could be.

Comment: In my response, I have taken the MessageBox out (sorry). Add `MessageBox.Show("works");` in the `if(counter ==0)`

Comment: I know I did that but I have no idea why it still doesn't work.

Comment: the problem is that your application adds items to the checkbox, but never removes them. my method checks to see if the items in the checkbox = 0. Because you dont remove the items, this will never happen. EDIT: Updated code

Comment: hmm I get it, so how can I remove a process from the checkbox when a process finishes?

Comment: It worked!! thanks a lot NewAmbition! I have been working on this project for months on and off. I appreciate your help. now I can download or install programs and when they are done it will shut off.

Comment: Awesome :D Happy to help.. Be sure to ask anything else if you need to!

Comment: actually it didn't sorry for the false alarm :( It seems that even though my process is running the message appears because the checklistbox is empty

Comment: Hmm these comments are getting a bit long, and it seems I'm providing solutions for that which isnt really needed by you. Go here
[link](http://www.rumbletalk.com/client/chat.php?1ZNsdj!d)

Comment: nothing still, I guess there's a reason why I can't find a application like this for C#. I saw this idea from Utorrent. when all of the torrents are done downloading you can have a setting to make the computer shutdown.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right place? Is it processes, or just methods in an application. It sounds to me that the process is still running, but the list doesn't pick it up after the timer?

Comment: well, to test the application I open up notepad checkmark the notepad's process name and then after clicking the start button after a few seconds I close notepad.

Comment: Replicated the code in my own application. This works for me.

Comment: And for me, thanks a lot I really appreciate it. I found the mistakes I had and it worked. Damn, this project was a pain but I'm glad it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `List<string>` representing your checkboxes, try:

```
List<string> checkProcs = new List<string>(); // All monitored process names
var allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().Select(p => p.ProcessName);

// Now use:
allProcesses.Except(checkProcs)
```

That should give a list of monitored processes that don't exist any more.

Comment: I love this solution the new C# is awesome